# WeakReference<T> return null while the target is a live

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I have written a message dispatcher where a reference to the each subscriber is stored as Reference

A part of the subscriber:

```
public Service(IMessageHub messageHub)
{
    Guard.NotNull(messageHub);

    messageHub.Subscribe<UserLogoutMessage>(UserLogOut);
}

~Service()
{
    // I have add it to check is it finalized or isn't it
    new object();
}

private void UserLogOut(UserLogoutMessage obj)
{
    GoToLoginPage();
}
```

The subscribe code of the MessageHub:

```
var weakRefference = new WeakReference<Action<TMessage>>(handler, true);
handlers.Add(weakRefference);

return new DisposeAction(() => Unsubscribe(weakRefference));
```

The send message code of the MessageHub:

```
foreach (var weakRefference in handlers.ToArray())
{
    Action<TMessage> handler;

    // The TryGetTarget method return false here
    if (weakRefference.TryGetTarget(out handler))
    {
        try
        {
            handler(message);
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    else
    {
        cleanRequired = true;
    }
}
```

Each time when I have tried to send message the weak reference returns null and my code doesn't work correct.
I have checked the Service still be available and doesn't finalized.
Could you help me to find root cause of the issue.

P.S. I'm developing to the Windows Phone 8 by the PCL

Comment: How do you know the object is still alive? Breakpoint in the finalizer?

Comment: The object is accessible by the roots and breakpoint in the finalizer + GC.Collect()

Comment: Try to reduce the problem to a simple repro (10 lines or so). In the process you'll find the bug. Maybe you put the wrong object into the weakref or you are looking at the wrong weakref. Just looking at the code will not bring you the solution. Start to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but in case anyone gets here from the search engines the problem is because you're storing a weak reference to the `Action<TMessage>`, which is a temporary object and, therefore, quite likely that is has been collected.

The solution is a bit more complicated; you'll basically have to store the parts of the delegate separately, as if you store the delegate with a strong reference you'll keep the target alive and, as you've seen, if you store the delegate with a weak reference it can be garbage collected while the target is still alive.

I think what you can do is store the `Target` property of the delegate in a weak reference and the result of `GetMethodInfo` stored in a separate field - when it's time to invoke the handler you just call the `Invoke` method of the `MethodInfo` with the object from the weak reference, if it's still alive.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I have solved it by my self, but any way thank you for the answer.